# Printing from android device using a usb printer without using third party print server

Tags: usb, printing

I would like to use a Brother HL-L2300D printer (USB printer) to print from my phone and tablet in my home network for convenience without the document going through a third party server or first turning on a PC. Right now I have connected the printer via USB to my router a FritzBox 7530.

---

I tried printing a test page with the app PrintBot (not yet purchased), which did work but I'm not so sure whether such an app ends up sending the documents to a server in order to process it to be able to print it, which I do not want for privacy reasons.
I also tried Let's Print Droid  but it does not work (probably because it seems to have no driver for low end Brother printers?).

I would prefer an open source app or at least an app that does not send the documents I'm printing (paid is fine) to a third party server.
If it really is not possible to print with this printer from an android device without a print server first processing the document I'll either just continue to turn on my PC every time when I need to print (when it's not already on anyway, obviously) something or buy a Raspberry Pi and run my own local print server.